# What's the difference between declaring array in main class or in main method?

Tags: java, arrays

I've been trying to declare an array in Java like tutorial says but received a mistake. Here's my code:

```
public class ArrayExample {

   private static final int SIZE = 15;

   /*   this works   */
   int[] arrayOfInt = new int[SIZE];

   /*  but this doesn't work, says "cannot find symbol"  */
   int[] arrOfInt;
   arrOfInt = new int[SIZE];


   public static void main(String[] args) {

      /*  but here it works; why? what's the difference? */
      int[] arrOfInt;
      arrOfInt = new int[SIZE];
   }
}
```

I couldn't find explanations of this difference in tutorial. Why the second declaration doesn't work but third one in `main` method works?

Comment: The one defined inside main() will simply be a local variable within the main function, not available anywhere else but inside that function. The ones defined above the main() function will  be members of the class, available to all methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can't write an assignment statement as part of a class definition.

Either use the first method (preferred) or move the assignment into the constructor (not necessary in this case, but could be useful if the size isn't known until the object is being constructed - then you can pass it in as a parameter to the constructor).

```
int[] arrOfInt;

public ArrayExample()
{
    arrOfInt = new int[SIZE];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even insert initialization of your variable into a class Anonymous code block, without using a constructor if you prefer, in this way :

```
int[] arrOfInt;

 {
arrOfInt = new int[SIZE];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do this

```
int[] arrayOfInt = new int[SIZE];
```

Compiler will read `arrayOfInt` and will remember to initialize it with `new int[SIZE]`.

Initialization of `arrayOfInt` wont happen at that moment.

When you do this:

```
int[] arrOfInt;
arrOfInt = new int[SIZE];
```

Compiler reads `arrOfInt` but when it reaches 2nd line it doesnt find the type of arrOfInt, remember compiler at this point may not have read all the variables hence it says it cannot find `arrOfInt`, in short it is not going to check if it has read a variable with same name of not as it is hasnt yet completed its complete processing and it is not in the initialization blocks. You are still in the declaration block of the code.

Method is a declaration + initialization block hence compiler lets you declare and initialize variable at two different points.

For initialization you can use either Constructor or Instance Initialization Block or Static Initialization Block.

- Static Initialization Block are executed once when class is loaded.
- Instance initialization Block are executed every time an instance of class is created and they will be executed as they are defined in the class after call to super is completed in the Constructor of the class.

Answer (score 0):

u can't declare nonstaic values into static methods  so this is wrong

```
int []arrOfInt;
public static void main(String[] args) {
      arrOfInt = new int[SIZE];
}
```

you can solve it like this

```
int []arrOfInt=new int[SIZE];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

or like this

```
class ArrayExample{
   int []arrOfInt;
   public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayExample a = new ArrayExample();
        a.arrOfInt=new int[a.SIZE];
   }
}
```